# Trouble rooting Bluestacks 0.9.3

Tags: rooting, bluestacks

I was using an older version of bluestacks on my computer and recently the update came, i had by old blustacks rooted using bsAutorooter but it doesnt seem to work on this new  update, if anyone has solutions regarding this please help me